# Dynamically Changing the Class Name for a DIV Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
 <div class="choices ui-grid-c" data-bind="foreach: choices">

                    <div class="ui-block-a"> </div>

</div>
```

I am using knockoutjs to iterate and create a list of grids. The inner div has the class "ui-block-a". I need to change this class to "ui-block-b" , "ui-block-c", "ui-block-d" with each iteration. After "ui-block-d" it should change back to "ui-block-a".

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper function on the parent:

```
self.blockClass = function(index) {
    var base = 'ui-block-';
    var blockIndex = index % 4;
    switch (blockIndex) {
      case 0:
        return base + 'a';
      case 1:
        return base + 'b';
      case 2:
        return base + 'c';
      case 3:
        return base + 'd';
    }
}
```

Then use css binding on it:

```
<div class="choices ui-grid-c" data-bind="foreach: choices">
    <div data-bind="css: $parent.blockClass($index())> </div>
</div>
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ns3g8of/)